I have a set of files but I can't apply the material in .ply
I have a set of files but I can't apply the material in .ply

The material does not go into .ply. Is there any tutorial you recommend in this case?

I'm trying to open his point cloud


Does this answer your question? Export cycles material to unity

Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather than point you to some tutorial, please [edit] to detail what you have tried and how it failed
